# Dual Domain - Works for child pages but not homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, dns, html, multiple-domains

I have a main site - something.com

Some other domains have A records in the DNS to point to the one above.

something.co

something.nl

I have this in my wp-config:

```
/*
 * Handle multi domain into single instance of wordpress installation
 */

define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

They both keep still going to the .com version if i try and go to their root.

If I go to a child page and then click on any other child page it is fine, unless i try and click home

https://something.nl/en/products/

I am not sure what else to try, and I can't find anything on Google to help.

Comment: So basically you want multiple domains (fleetcomplete.com, fleetcomplete.co, fleetcomplete.nl) to go to the same Wordpress site?

Comment: It looks like you're using the solution (Google "Mapping Multiple Domains into Single Instance of WordPress"). Can you check inside the WordPress Settings -> General to see if WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) are disabled? Maybe your domain is set somewhere else in the database and it is defaulting to that.

Comment: Hi Adam,
They are disabled in Settings > General.  The only other place i can see them in the DB is in the _options table

Comment: httacess might be the culprit. Looks like you're forwarding all traffic ("(.*)$") to the ".com" address.

Comment: I removed it, but still no luck :-(

Comment: Mapping multiple domains to the same website is usually not a good idea. This will reduce the SEO because search engines will penalize you for duplicate content. You should pick one domain as your canonical domain and redirect the others to that one.

Answer (score 2):

This was the answer i needed :-) The Polylang plugin was causing the issue.

define('PLL_CACHE_HOME_URL', false);